# Export an intersection of features as a raster Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am using Google Earth Engine to export some clipped images I am interested, but I need to export the region which I am using to clip the images as a geoTIFF, in this case, the feature called `protectedAreas`, I can't find any examples of doing this. Below is the code I use to export images, so instead I would like to export the feature.

```js
// Define start and end ee.Dates.
var startDate = ee.Date('2000-01-01');
var endDate = ee.Date('2010-01-01');


// Define the regional bounds 
var region = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[139.81147500927887, -22.584034738321385],
          [139.81147500927887, -39.52984428265981],
          [155.19233438427887, -39.52984428265981],
          [155.19233438427887, -22.584034738321385]]], null, false);

// Subset the to a Country .
var congo = ee.Feature(
  region
);

// Load a FeatureCollection from a table dataset: 'RESOLVE' ecoregions.
var ecoregions = ee.FeatureCollection('RESOLVE/ECOREGIONS/2017');


// Subset o the bounds of the ecoregion feature
// and other criteria. Clip to the intersection with congo.
var protectedAreas = ecoregions
  .filter(ee.Filter.and(
    ee.Filter.bounds(congo.geometry()),
    ee.Filter.eq('BIOME_NUM', 4)             // 4 = TBMF AUstralia, 1=TMBF Amazonia
  ))
  .map(function(feat){
    return congo.intersection(feat,ee.ErrorMargin(1));
  });

Map.addLayer(protectedAreas, {}, 'Eco region ');

var fire = ee.ImageCollection('FIRMS')
             .filterDate(startDate, endDate);

//print(fire)
// Clip and add a date band
var clipToRegion = function(img) {
  var clipped = img.clip(protectedAreas);
  return clipped;
};

var fire_clipped =fire.map(clipToRegion)

var scale = fire_clipped.first().projection().nominalScale().getInfo();

Map.addLayer(fire_clipped.first(), {}, 'Fire clipped');

Export.image.toDrive({
    image: fire_clipped.first(),
    description: 'Fires',
    scale: scale,
    region: region,
    fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',
    formatOptions: {
      cloudOptimized: true
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need just a raster footprint, the easiest way is to create a constant image with global extent and then just clip by your `protectedAreas` AOI.

```
var rasterFootprint = ee.Image(0).clip(protectedAreas)
```

Then you export it the same way as you did with `fire_clipped.first()` Image.

[Here's a link to code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/a91ea7b1e70a262ad380ea83b26620b8)

Other option is to use `reduceToImage()` method on your `protectedAreas` `FeatureCollection`. Then you can retain some `Feature` metadata, if needed.